# Compare dates and set it as "first day of the Week" or "new Month"

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, azure-sql-database

Currently I am manipulating a date column and setting it to the first day of the Week. Example: 23rd August'2023 would be set to 20th August'2023 using `select DATEADD(day, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2023/08/25'), '2023/08/25')`  However there are dates in this case which belong to a new month, Example: 1st September'2023 which gets assigned to 27th August'2023 but it should get assigned to the new month calculation. How do I calculate this?
I am using SQL Server:

> Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jul  8 2023 12:00:47**

Any way I can compare the month and if it is greater than current month, then it gets assigned to the new next week?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
DATEADD(day, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2023/09/01'), '2023/09/01')` -- assigns to first week

case
    when DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(day, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2023/09/01'), '2023/09/01')) > DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) THEN "assign it to new month"
else DATEADD(day, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2023/09/01'), '2023/09/01')
```

This is what I am expecting that it compares the month number to current month and if it is greater then it assigns to new month else it `DATEADD(day, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2023/09/01'), '2023/09/01')` assigns to first week.

| Input | Output | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-23 00:00:00.000 | 2023-08-20 00:00:00.000 | first day of the week which is sunday in sql server |
| 2023-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-03 00:00:00.000 | first day of the week in the new month since the date belongs to new month even though it is in the last week of August on calendar |

Comment: Dates are binary values, not localized strings like `2023/09/01`. To avoid unfortunate conversions use either `2023-09-01` or `20230901` for date literals. What's the actual type of the column? `date`? Also, what's the logic? The start of the week for `2023-09-02` *is* August 28. You're asking for either the start of the week *or* the start of the month, whichever is bigger

Comment: i think it would help if you attach a markdown table in form of: "input value" , "expected output value". Make sure to include all the various cases. I'm pretty sure this problem has been solved many times though, have you actually searched stackoverflow?

Comment: The fast way to solve calendar-related problems is to create a Calendar table with eg 10-20 years of precalculated dates along with extra columns needed for analysis and reporting, eg Year, Month, Semester, Quarter, WeekNumber, StartOfMonth,StartOfWeek, etc. You can join this table on any `date`-typed columns and aggregate by whatever period you want and easily perform eg quarter over quarter or year over year comparisons.

Comment: As you're on Azure SQL Database, why not use `DATETRUNC` to get the first day of the week?

Comment: What's the actual version of the database? Are you using a compatibility level? Azure SQL is the latest SQL Server version but  `12.0.2000.8` is a SQL Server 2014 version which went out of support a *long* time ago. If you *remove* the compatibility level you'll be able to use `GREATEST` to return either the start of week or month, whichever is greatest

Comment: You can probably use `GREATEST(DATETRUNC(week,my_date_col),DATETRUNC(month,my_date_col))`

Comment: I have edited my question and have added inputs and outputs @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Azure SQL Database always returns `12.0.2000.8` for `@@VERSION` - this doesn't tell us anything about the compatibility level they are using.

Comment: *"first day of the week which is sunday in sql server"* This isn't true, the language setting you are using determines the first day of the week. For me, for example, `DATETRUNC(WEEK,GETDATE())` returns `2023-08-21`, *not* `2023-08-20`. If I were American, then it would return the latter. For an ISO Week, it is *always* Monday.  [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R81us9Iq)

Comment: @brins did you try `DATETRUNC` ?

Comment: Should work. I don't see any specific compatibility requirements for it. If you are on Azure SQL database you can use it. I guess an advantage of demanding user scalar UDFs are schema qualified is that they can make new built in scalar functions available at all compat levels

Comment: @MartinSmith why did you delete your answer? Based on the question that does seem to be the answer the OP is after.

Comment: My answer does not return 3rd september for 1st september input (as apparently desired from the comment on the other answer) and I lost interest in seeing why that was the desired result TBH

Comment: Oh, yeah, that makes no sense...

Answer (score 1):

Please find below working code based on your requirement. On top of your logic, I have modified little bit alone. **If the month of arrived date is less than the month of given date, add 7 days(which will give first sunday of new month).** Please mark it as answer if it works for you. Let me know the outcome.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(day, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2023/09/01'), '2023/09/01')) < DATEPART(MONTH, '2023/09/01')
        THEN DATEADD(day, 7, DATEADD(day, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2023/09/01'), '2023/09/01'))
        ELSE DATEADD(day, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2023/09/01'), '2023/09/01')
```

Comment: Of course this can be optimzed further. But let me know if it works for you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Below are two ways to do it; one is with just plain SQL, the other is as a UFN.

```
--Just using a SELECT statement (no non-native functions)
declare @d datetime = '2023-09-01 00:00:00.000'
select
  format(
    case when month(@d) = month(dateadd(day,1-datepart(weekday,@d),@d))
         then dateadd(day,1-datepart(weekday,@d),@d)
         else dateadd(day,8-datepart(weekday,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,@d),0)),DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,@d),0))
    end
  ,'d') as "Date, rounded down to most recent Sunday (or first Sunday of the month)"
/*
Output:
9/3/2023
*/
go
if object_id('UFN_DATEROUNDDOWN') is not null
  drop function UFN_DATEROUNDDOWN
go
create function UFN_DATEROUNDDOWN
(
  @d datetime
)
returns datetime
as
begin
  --Given a date, return date of the first day of that week (Sunday).
  --UNLESS
  --that would cause the date to roll back into a prior month.
  --in that case, return the 1st sunday of the month instead.
  declare @weekstart datetime = dateadd(day,1-datepart(weekday,@d),@d)
  declare @monthstart datetime = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,@d),0)
  declare @firstweekstart_newmonth datetime = dateadd(day,8-datepart(weekday,@monthstart),@monthstart)
  
  return
    case when month(@d) = month(@weekstart)
         then @weekstart
         else @firstweekstart_newmonth
    end
end
go
declare @d datetime
declare @r table(inputdate datetime, outputdate datetime)
set @d = '2023-08-20';insert into @r select @d,dbo.ufn_daterounddown(@d)
set @d = '2023-08-21';insert into @r select @d,dbo.ufn_daterounddown(@d)
set @d = '2023-08-22';insert into @r select @d,dbo.ufn_daterounddown(@d)
set @d = '2023-08-23';insert into @r select @d,dbo.ufn_daterounddown(@d)
set @d = '2023-09-01';insert into @r select @d,dbo.ufn_daterounddown(@d)
set @d = '2023-09-02';insert into @r select @d,dbo.ufn_daterounddown(@d)
set @d = '2023-09-03';insert into @r select @d,dbo.ufn_daterounddown(@d)
SELECt
  format(inputdate,'d')  as "Input date"
 ,format(outputdate,'d') as "Output date"
FROM
  @R
/*
Results:
Input date | Output date
========================
8/20/2023  | 8/20/2023
8/21/2023  | 8/20/2023
8/22/2023  | 8/20/2023
8/23/2023  | 8/20/2023
9/1/2023   | 9/3/2023
9/2/2023   | 9/3/2023
9/3/2023   | 9/3/2023
*/
```

Comment: How do I but assign 1st September date to new week of new month? which is 3rd September @JosephStyons

Comment: my output for 1st september as in my question should be 3rd september ( first day of the week in a new month or the "very next week first day" )

Comment: @brins i just updated the answer based on your clarification.

Comment: Why should 2023-09-03 return 2023-09-01, @brins ? 2023-09-03 is the first day of the week, so why do you go *back* to the start of the month?